# What are the stages in the .explain() output

Tags: mongodb

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/) give some examples of what can appear in the stage field, but I can't find a definitive list of what the valid values are in there and what they mean.

> Stages are descriptive of the operation; e.g.
>
> COLLSCAN for a collection scan
>
> IXSCAN for scanning index keys
>
> FETCH for retrieving documents
>
> SHARD_MERGE for merging results from shards

Could anyone explain them to me, or point me at somewhere definitive?

Answer (score -1):

As I can see in the book "MongoDB Data Modeling", it is written that

> There are **four stages**:

and than the name and description of each at page # 88, and as you wrote in the docs also only 4 are given so may be we can conclude that there are 4 only.

[google books link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=R5_5CQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA88&dq=mongodb%20winningplan%20stages&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q=mongodb%20winningplan%20stages&f=false)

Comment: Thanks, I can't get to that book.  There is definitely more than that four though. e.g. KEEP_MUTATIONS

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: No, maybe someone will come along and prove me wrong.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011166/mongodb-keep-mutation-stage-explain